# MongoDB: Get single document with specific parent id and highest order value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My documents have the key `order`, which is an ascending numeric value.

Now I would like to get the highest order value of all documents which has a specific parent value.

What I am doing is (I'm using mongo native driver)

- find all documents with the specific parent id
- sort the result in descending order
- limit to 1 document

I'm doing this, as I think `findOne` can't sort the documents. Am I right with that?

```
const last = await Content.find({ parent: parentID }).sort({ order: -1 }).limit(1).toArray()
console.log(last[0].order)
```

Now I get an array with a single document. But is it possible to get only the document itself without returning the result as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [findOne](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#find-first-occurence-with-findone) like this:

```
var options = {
    "sort": [['order','desc']]
};

Content.findOne({ parent: parentID }, options, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: @user3142695: LOL, yeah, obviously. I'm sorry. ;)